# Variables in Adhearsion

Tags: asterisk

How can I pass in a variable to the dailplan.rb file.

dial 'SIP/976', :for => 15.seconds

How can I make it so that I can specify the extension from outside the file.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are just talking about Ruby string interpolation.  The easiest way to make the dialed extension variable is to use Ruby:

```
myexten = '976'
dial "SIP/#{myexten}", :for => 15.seconds
```

Remember to use double quotes if you are going to use the #{} to insert a variable into the string.

You may also be referring to Asterisk channel variables.  Assuming we are talking about Adhearsion 1.x, if you want to set a variable prior to the dial, use the #set_variable syntax:

```
set_variable 'MYVAR', "this is the value of the MYVAR channel variable"
set_variable 'OUTBOUND_GROUP', 'group1'
dial 'SIP/976', :for => 15.seconds
```

If you want to retrieve the value of a channel variable (such as those set as a result of the #dial) you can use get_variable:

```
dial 'SIP/976', :for => 15.seconds
ahn_log.info "Call completed with status #{get_variable 'DIALSTATUS'}"
```